# Checkboxes issue in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have html that has a lot of checkboxes. Some of the checkboxes should uncheck group of other checkboxes.So one of the checkboxe have the following code.

The first version is in Jquery`

```
function uncheckmusic() {
    $(".buttons :checkbox").prop('checked',false);
}

$("#test").click(function() {
    uncheckmusic();
}
```

The other version is in Javascript`

```
function uncheckmusic() {
    document.getElementById("first").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("second").checked = false;      
}

$("#test").click(function() {
    uncheckmusic();
}
```

So the problem is the following.In the Firefox it works fine but in webkit browsers (for instance Chrome) there is some issue which i cannot understand. Checkboxes do not return value or do not update. Please help me.

```
<div class="classexample">             
    <input id="test" name="yesmusic" class="toggle"  type="checkbox">                                     
</div>                       

<div class="buttons">                  
      <input id="first" name="checkbox1"  type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <div id="checkbox1"><b>checkbox1</b></div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">                  
    <input id="second" name="checkbox2"  type="checkbox2" class="toggle">
    <div id="checkbox2"><b>checkbox2</b></div>                        
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell... Can you post a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: it's actually `getElementsByClassName`, and it returns a nodeList that you have to iterate over, not an element.

Comment: And it's actually `$('.buttons[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);` in jQuery

Comment: Have Checkboxes class buttons or checkboces inside element with same class?

Comment: do you have any jsfiddle?

Comment: Check it now.thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you set checked to `null` instead of `false`?

Comment: No in that case it does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps you, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/bJ5xK/).

```
<script>
$(function() {

  function uncheckmusic() {
    $('.buttons input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
  }

  $('.buttons input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('.classexample input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
    }
  });

  $('.classexample input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       uncheckmusic();
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: As i said in firefox it works well but in Chrome for instance it does not work. I think there is something wrong with Jquery about the click event and the checkbox.

Comment: Ok but if you look at my Fiddle you'll see that works in Chrome.